# Find parameters such that the limit should exist

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Consider: $\lim \limits _{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\pi(1-cos^mx)}{x^n}$.

The question is to find the value of $m$ and $n$ such that the limit above should exist. If one applies L'Hospitals rule, it is ending nowhere.
I want to use $1-\cos x=2\sin^2 \frac x 2$ or $1-\cos^2x=\sin^2x$,but as it is $1-\cos^mx$ nothing could be done. Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking here. Are you asking: For which values of $m$ and $n$ does L'Hospital's Rule _not_ provide an answer?

Comment: I am asking what are the possible values of m and n.

Comment: Subject to _what_?

Comment: such that the limit exists i guess @CarlHeckman

Comment: Put a \ in front of the lim and cos ...

Comment: @MathsLover: Editing to improve a post is good, but if you do it then better do it fully and properly.

Comment: @AlexM. , You are right. I didn't notice the title of the question. So, I apologize for not editing it too. It's the first time I edit another question so I missed that. I will make sure to do the job fully next times. thank you for pointing this out :) .

Answer (score 1):

This is a strange question, which I doubt to be homework.

The limit is $$\lim_{x\to0} {1-\cos^m x \over x^n}.$$ (The $\pi$ is irrelevant.) The question is to determine for which values of $m,n\ge 0$, does L'Hospital's Rule (abbreviated as LHR) give a value for this limit.

If $m=0$ or $n=0$, then LHR doesn't need to be used; hence, we assume $n>0$ from here on.

Using LHR, we see the original limit is equal to $$\lim_{x\to0} {m\sin x \cos^{m-1} x\over nx^{n-1}}={m \over n}\lim_{x\to0} {\sin x\cos^{m-1} x \over x^{n-1}}.$$ Now, if the limit of the denominator is not zero, LHR works. But this happens iff $n=1$, so (so far) we know that LHR determines the limit if $m=0$, $n=0$ or $n=1$.

What if the denominator is zero, though? Then our new limit is of the form ${0\over 0}$, so we use LHR again.

Using LHR again (ignoring the ${m\over n}$ factor), we obtain the new limit
$$\lim_{x\to0} {\cos^m x -(m-1)\sin^2 x \cos^{m-2}x\over (n-1)x^{n-2}}.$$
Once again, if $n=2$, then LHR gives us the value, because we won't be dividing by zero. Now suppose that $n\ge 3$. The limit of the numerator is easily seen to be $1$, so LHR can't be used any more.

So the answer is: LHR will solve the problem iff $m=0$ or $0 \le n \le 2$.

Comment: This is not a homework,i am searching to do this problem for many months,cannot do.

Comment: Then I hope I haven't goofed. (I used Maple to calculate the derivatives of the numerators.) OTOH, if I _have_ goofed, then you'll have to fix the details; the method should be sound.

Answer (score 0):

Given $$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\pi\cdot (1-\cos^{m} x)}{x^n} = \bf{Limit\; exists.}$$

Now Using $$\bullet\; \displaystyle \cos x = 1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+....\infty$$ and $$ \bullet\; \displaystyle (1+x)^n = 1+nx+\frac{n(n-1)x^2}{2}+...\infty$$

Now $$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\cos x \approx 1-\frac{x^2}{2}$$

So Our Limit  is $$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\pi \left[1-\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)^{m}\right]}{x^n} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\pi\left[1-\left(1-\frac{mx^2}{2}+\frac{m(m-1)}{2}\cdot \frac{x^4}{4}-...\infty\right)\right]}{x^n}$$

So we get $$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\pi x^2\left[\frac{m}{2}-\frac{m(m-1)}{8}x^2+....\infty\right]}{x^n} = \bf{Limit\; exists}$$

So for the existance of limit, Here $n\leq 2$ and $m\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: I think you mean $n \le 2$. When $n=1$, the limit is zero. (Also, you didn't use LHR, so you answered a different question.) Also, when $m=0$, the limit exists (trivially).

Comment: Yes Carl Heckman you are right.